# Computing the logdeterminant of a Sparse Matrix in Julia

Tags: julia, sparse-matrix, determinants, matrix-factorization

I'm interested in computing the log of the determinant of a large, sparse, complex (floating point) matrix. My first thought is to use an LU decomposition, i.e.:

```
srand(123) 
A=complex.(rand(3,3), rand(3,3))

LUF=lufact(A)
LUFs=lufact(sparse(A))

if round(det(LUFs[:L])*det(LUFs[:U])-det(A[LUFs[:p], LUFs[:q]]), 5)==0
    println("Sparse LU determinant is correct\n")
else
    println("Sparse LU determinant is NOT correct\n")
end
```

which will always print out the "NOT correct" option. Furthermore,

```
round.(LUFs[:L]*LUFs[:U], 5)==round.(A[LUFs[:p], LUFs[:q]], 5)
```

always comes out as false.

If instead I try to directly use

```
logdet(LUFs)
```

or

```
logdet(sparse(A))
```

I get an error:

```
LoadError: MethodError: no method matching
logabsdet(::Base.SparseArrays.UMFPACK.UmfpackLU{Complex{Float64},Int64})
Closest candidates are:
logabsdet(!Matched::Base.LinAlg.UnitUpperTriangular{T,S} where S<:
(AbstractArray{T,2} where T)) where T at linalg/triangular.jl:2184
logabsdet(!Matched::Base.LinAlg.UnitLowerTriangular{T,S} where S<:
(AbstractArray{T,2} where T)) where T at linalg/triangular.jl:2185
logabsdet(!Matched::Union{LowerTriangular{T,S} where S<:
(AbstractArray{T,2} where T), UpperTriangular{T,S} where S<:
(AbstractArray{T,2} where T)}) where T at linalg/triangular.jl:2189
...
while loading...
```

I'm not sure if it's something wrong in the way I've coded it (I'm a beginner transitioning from matlab), or if there's something wrong with my Julia install (though I have replicated these results on another computer). Any pointers you could give me would be great!

Comment: How close is it? It might just be floatingpoint rounding error.

Comment: You should almost never use `==` to compare the results of a floating point calculation, especially ones that go through a multithreaded BLAS. This is true for programming in any language. There will be some rounding error just by virtue of how these numbers work.

Comment: That's a really good point, but it's off by an order of magnitude. For the rng seed above, I get det(LUFs[:L])*det(LUFs[:U])=0.0216… - 0.00358…im and det(A)=0.458… - 0.0759…im.

Comment: (edited to address this point)

Comment: How much does speed matter? Use SVD decomposition and do something like `log(complex(det(U))) + sum(log.(d)) + logdet(complex(det(T)))`.

Comment: speed is probably somewhat flexible, but trying `svdfact(sparse(A))`, I get a similar error message to that for `logdet(sparse(A))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the sparse LU has a scaling factor as well which can be extracted with `LUFs[:Rs]` (in Julia 0.6 and `LUFs.Rs` in Julia 0.7-). Hence the computation becomes

```
julia> det(LUFs[:U])/prod(LUFs[:Rs])
0.4576579970452131 - 0.07585833005688908im

julia> det(A)
0.4576579970452133 - 0.07585833005688908im
```

We should probably have `logabsdet` for the sparse case as well. However, is your matrix positive definite by any chance? In so, you'd be able to compute the `logdet` of the Cholesky factorization.

Comment: Unfortunately my matrix isn't positive definite, but adding in the scaling factor fixes my issue. Thank you!